# Selecting elements that are less than a particular value as cluster heads

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, loss

I wrote some code for clustering a list of elements then select one element from each group with a minimum loss value.

```
import warnings
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from tabulate import tabulate
%matplotlib inline
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

loss_data = np.array([1.453158736228, 4.71358454227, 2.22189044952, 1.369125723838, 1.294319868087, 3.604614257, 1.282392263412,
1.035766720771, 3.537582755088, 1.647409796714, 2.12351524829, 1.522501230239, 1.092259526252, 3.8876036, 2.12351319])

df=loss_data.reshape(-1, 1)
```

then I cluster the elements based on their loss values with kmean

```
Tabel 1: element with their Clusters
+----+-----------+------------+---------+
|    |   element |   Clusters |    loss |
|----+-----------+------------+---------|
|  0 |         0 |          0 | 1.45316 |
|  1 |         1 |          1 | 4.71358 |
|  2 |         2 |          2 | 2.22189 |
|  3 |         3 |          0 | 1.36913 |
|  4 |         4 |          0 | 1.29432 |
|  5 |         5 |          1 | 3.60461 |
|  6 |         6 |          0 | 1.28239 |
|  7 |         7 |          0 | 1.03577 |
|  8 |         8 |          1 | 3.53758 |
|  9 |         9 |          0 | 1.64741 |
| 10 |        10 |          2 | 2.12352 |
| 11 |        11 |          0 | 1.5225  |
| 12 |        12 |          0 | 1.09226 |
| 13 |        13 |          1 | 3.8876  |
| 14 |        14 |          2 | 2.12351 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+
```

MY question is how could I update my code to select heads from each cluster that has loss below (eg, 3).

The results should look like

```
Tabel: heads of each  Cluster with loss below 3
+----+-----------+------------+---------+
|    |   element |   Clusters |    loss |
|----+-----------+------------+---------|
|  0 |         0 |          0 | 1.45316 |
|  2 |         2 |          2 | 2.22189 |
|  3 |         3 |          0 | 1.36913 |
|  4 |         4 |          0 | 1.29432 |
|  6 |         6 |          0 | 1.28239 |
|  7 |         7 |          0 | 1.03577 |
|  9 |         9 |          0 | 1.64741 |
| 10 |        10 |          2 | 2.12352 |
| 11 |        11 |          0 | 1.5225  |
| 12 |        12 |          0 | 1.09226 |
| 14 |        14 |          2 | 2.12351 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+
```

When I tried to use min_losses = [[loss[elem]] for elem in elems if loss[elem] < 3]
I faced the following error:

**---> 15     min_ind = min_losses.index(min_loss_temp)**

```
ValueError: [[ 1.45316], [1.36913], [ 1.29432], [ 1.29432], [1.03577], [1.64741], [1.5225], [1.09226 ]] is not in list
```

Comment: do you just wan't all values less than a particular value? if so, `df_clusters.loc[df_clusters.loss<3]` will work

Comment: @SajanGohil, I know this way, but I need to modify my code  from the line for j in range(len(clusters)): to return the index of heads (elements) in this case (all values less than a particular value).

Comment: Do you mean that you want the minimum loss for each class, after filtering the values? Do you want your esult to look like the last table or 2nd last table but with values less than threshold?

Comment: @ SajanGohil, I meant that I want to use the same code for return min loss of each group but for threshold, to have an index of each element  (line code from for j in range(len(clusters)): to clust_heads.append(elems[min_ind])).

Comment: Do you mean `if min_loss_temp >= 3: continue`? or something like `min_losses = [[loss[elem]] for elem in elems if loss[elem] < 3]`? If you can try to make your problem and expected result more clear in the question, that will be helpful.

Comment: @ SajanGohil, I meant to save each loss (min_losses) of each cluster into dataframe  that loss >= 3
but I faced this problem with  if min_loss_temp >= 3: continue: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: If that's the issue, you should post that as part of your question. min_loss is a list of values, so you will have to filter the values in the list. (just fyi, ideally, you should use pandas functions and operate on df_clusters)